# Playing music with ALSA in LINUX

Tags: c++, linux, alsa

I have a player class which writes into sound card using ALSA functions under Linux with RT patch. Do you know whether ALSA can provide me microsecond granularity while playing audio? In addition, what should I do in case I want to play the audio not at the time I receive but another time in the near future. Should I just call usleep function for example or is there any better way?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your actual concern? Why do you want to play sound "but not now"? What is the importance of "microsecond granularity" [I understand what the term means, I'm trying to understand why it's important in this case - e.g. are you worried that the driver will interfere with other proceses, or are you worried about the accuracy of samples being played out at a precise time, or something else?]

Comment: I am multicasting an audio stream to two different receivers and my main concern is that these two players may not play at the same time. I am just trying to understand how I could synchronize them.

Comment: I suspect that's not possible...